# Merge the csv files in GCP

Tags: python, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, data-preprocessing, google-cloud-vertex-ai

The dataset on which I am working on GCP is in csv format and for each feature there is a separate csv file with no header. There is around 20 files and want to create a single file for all these variables with headers. However, I have access on the data bucket only when I try to open Vertex AI Workbench, it shows I don't have permission for that.
Is there any way to combine all these files?

Comment: Do you want to append to file at the bottom or at the right (one file per column in your final CSV file)?

Comment: Please check -> Stack Overflow good posting etiquette:
- https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
- https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I need to append at the bottom and as well as right. because I have different files for different features which i want to append at the right. and I have more than one file for the same feature which i want to append at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

I [wrote an article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/merge-clean-transform-your-csvs-easily-with-bigquery-3a73c0c26d57) on how to use BigQuery to play with CSV files. I didn't mentioned how to merge to right. But typically I will do a join on row_number, something like that:

```
With table_left as (select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () as row_id from <tableLeft>),
table_right as (select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () as row_id from <tableRight>)
select tl.* except(row_id), tr.*  except(row_id) from table_left tl join table_right tr on tl.row_id = tr.row_id
```